# Torch operation on nn.Parameter

Tags: pytorch

I have a list of parameters and I would like to sum all the elements in the list

```
import torch
from torch import nn

a = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1))
b = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1))

my_list = [a, b]
torch.sum(*my_list)
```

I receive the error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<input>", line 8, in <module>
> TypeError: sum() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Parameter, Parameter), but expected one of:
>  * (Tensor input, *, torch.dtype dtype)
>  * (Tensor input, tuple of ints dim, bool keepdim, *, torch.dtype dtype, Tensor out)
>  * (Tensor input, tuple of names dim, bool keepdim, *, torch.dtype dtype, Tensor out)
> ```

I was wondering if there is a way to perform operations like `torch.sum` on `Parameter`s?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to access a for example which is a nn.Parameter()
with a.data that returns a torch tensor. I hope that helps.

try to print a's .data field to get some intuition:

```
print(a.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to concatenate tensors using torch.stack and then sum.

`import torch`

`from torch import nn`

`a=nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1))`

`b=nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1))`

`l=[a,b]`

`l1=torch.stack(l,dim=0)`

`torch.sum(l)`